# Using google analyics with my REST API

Tags: json, rest, google-analytics, analytics

My site provides public JSON API. I want to track usage of this API (like I do for webpages) with google analytics. How can I track API usage?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: Sure, I tried, but didn't find anything, that's why I am asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I can use GA for mobile apps. It's serverside. Docs: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/other/mobileWebsites

Well, I guess, I'll have to port ga lib to python in my case :)

UPD: Oh, b1tr0t already done it for us: https://github.com/b1tr0t/Google-Analytics-for-Mobile--python-

UPD2: Found a fork which seems to be a bit more useful: https://github.com/singhj/Google-Analytics-for-Mobile--Google-App-Engine

**UPD3:** I've made a small library based on mentioned above, it's more pythonic, and has out-of-the-box support for flask and django - https://bitbucket.org/DataGreed/pyga/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could look at something like [this](http://code.google.com/p/php-ga/) or [this](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2012/01/20/Tracking-API-usage-with-Google-Analytics.aspx)? Depending on your implementation, of course.

Comment: Well, my app is written in python, using flask. I actually thought that there may be some google's reference for GA api to use in this case, but i didn't find any

Comment: Indeed, Google itself seems to be just interested in web pages that allow Javascript, plus mobile platforms..

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.